# wp8: How to get bing daily image

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Using C#, I am trying to figure out how to set the Bing's "picture of the day" as an lock screen background.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,
Bijjol.

Comment: Looks like the tag: `<div id="bgDiv" class=" sw_imLd" style="height: 768px; width: 1366px; top: -97.5px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; background-image: url(http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/OvisDalli_EN-US10633584978_1366x768.jpg); visibility: visible;"><div id="hp_vidwrp"></div><video id="vid" onended="VM.pause();" autobuffer="" preload="auto" oncontextmenu="return false" style="height: 768px; width: 1366px; top: -97.5px; left: 0px;"></video></div>` works, to get the `background-image: url(http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/OvisDalli_EN-US10633584978_1366x768.jpg`

Comment: My bad, i should have mentioned, I was trying to do this on a windows phone.

Comment: Doesn't really change anything, your using .NET and .NET has classes to help get webpages / html. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an endpoint that I found a while ago, that returns specific Windows Phone-sized (adjusted to the screen resolution) Bing wallpapers, available here:

```
http://appserver.m.bing.net/BackgroundImageService/TodayImageService.svc/GetTodayImage
```

You need to build a custom request, like this, to get the image:

```
http://appserver.m.bing.net/BackgroundImageService/TodayImageService.svc/GetTodayImage?dateOffset=0&urlEncodeHeaders=true&osName=wince&osVersion=7.10&orientation=480x800&deviceName=WP7Device&mkt=en-US&AppId=1
```

Comment: Thank you.
I had found this link as well, but I am not sure how to retrieve the image using that link. Would you by any chance have any code snippet to get the image?

Comment: You have the URL. Now all you need to do is issue a GET request to actually fetch the content. HttpWebRequest is your friend in this case.

Comment: You have an error in your link, the `x` symbol is not the right one, this is the fixed link:
http://appserver.m.bing.net/BackgroundImageService/TodayImageService.svc/GetTodayImage?dateOffset=0&urlEncodeHeaders=true&osName=wince&osVersion=7.10&orientation=480x800&deviceName=WP7Device&mkt=en-US&AppId=1

`http://appserver.m.bing.net/BackgroundImageService/TodayImageService.svc/GetTodayImage?dateOffset=0&urlEncodeHeaders=true&osName=wince&osVersion=7.10&orientation=480x800&deviceName=WP7Device&mkt=en-US&AppId=1`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

You can read the [XML](http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US) or [JSON](http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1) provided by Bing Service and wrap it as you wish.

Happy coding.